# Role Select Menu | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have ran into a problem with my selectMenu code. There's no error in the console, but the slash command won't show up. Maybe there's problem in the code? I've spent over 30 minutes trying to the problem and yet I couldn't find it.

````
require('dotenv').config();
const { RoleSelectMenuBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ComponentType } = require('discord.js');

const data = {
    name: 'show-roles',
    description: 'Show roles using role select menu.',
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {import('discord.js').ChatInputCommandInteraction} param0.interaction
 */

async function run({ interaction }) {
    const roleMenu = new RoleSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId(interaction.id)
        .setMinValues(0)
        .setMaxValues(3);

    const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().setComponents(roleMenu);

    const reply = await interaction.reply({ components: [actionRow]});

    const collector = reply.createMessageComponentCollector({
        componentType: ComponentType.RoleSelect,
        filter: (i) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.customId === interaction.id, time: 60_000,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (interaction) => {
        if  (!interaction.values.length) {
            interaction.reply('You have emptied your selection.');
            return;
        }

        interaction.reply(
            `You have now selected: ${interaction.values.join(', ')}`);
    })
}

module.exports = { data, run };

try {
    console.log(`----- YOUR'RE GOOD TO GO! -----`)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
};```


I tried to make a role menu selector but the slash command for it doesn't work. I'd like to find a solution how to fix this problem
````

Comment: If the slashcommand isn't showing up in discord you're probably registering your commands wrong. Could you edit the question and include that?


I am also a little confused about the try{} cacht{} block at the end of your file. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Hey @RogueMan, I don't know why I added the trycatch. I fixed the slash command not showing up, but it won't send the menu. Do you know why?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console? I have copied your code and tried it myself but I do get a menu returned when executing the command. Are you sure the command actually gets executed?